# How to inject a factory dependency into Angular provider factory method

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 9 (9.1.4) project and there is a custom factory provider for BASE_URL (the project is based on .NET Core Angular template)

```js
// main.ts

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}

const providers = [
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] }
];

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

If I want to use the BASE_URL in a class, its super easy, I can just ask for it to be injected in the constructor

```js
export class SomeService {

  constructor(
    private _httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private _baseUrl: string  // here we go
  ) { }
```

and it works as expected. So far so good...

I recently added an `APP_INITIALIZER` to the app, so I can load some configuration from server up-front. This is done by registering a provider with factory function, into which dependencies can also be injected.

However, the simple approach using @Inject does not work there for some reason:

```js
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  // other stuff
  providers: [
    SomeService, // here the @Inject works
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) => {
        // httpClient is OK, but baseUrl is undefined
        // app init implementation
      },
      deps: [HttpClient],
      multi: true
    }],
```

because baseUrl is undefined during runtime.

The only way I could get it to work was to inject the Injector from @angular/core:

```js
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient, injector: Injector) => {
    cont baseUrl = injector.get('BASE_URL'); // works, but deprecated
    // app init implementation
  },
  deps: [HttpClient, Injector],
  multi: true
}
```

but there the problem is the deprecation warning on `get` method (deprecated since v4.0.0).

What's the proper way to get such factory injection working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to provide the desired value in the same way as you do it with `HttpClient`.

Since the value is a simple string a custom [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) is needed:

base-url.ts (I used a separate file to avoid a circular dependency)

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

export const BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('BaseUrl');

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BASE_URL } from "../base-url";
// ...
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient, baseUrl: string) => {
      return () => {
        console.log(baseUrl);
        return Promise.resolve();
      };
    },
    deps: [HttpClient, BASE_URL], // <-- Here
    multi: true
  }],
// ...
```

**Edit**
Yes, actually, a string could be used as a token so adding it as a second value to `deps` array does a trick. The initial problem was in fact that it is not possible to decorate function's (not method's) arguments and that is why in case of injecting a factory `deps` array is used.
So, this works:

```
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (httpClient: HttpClient, baseUrl: string) => {
      return () => {
        console.log(baseUrl);
        return Promise.resolve();
      };
    },
    deps: [HttpClient, 'BASE_URL'], // <-- Here
    multi: true
  }],
```

But I would really advice use `InjectionToken` instead because it is safier. Please also note that the deprecation warning you've got for `injector.get('BASE_URL');` relates to string tokens, since [only the signature of `get` that accepts stings is depricated](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get).

Comment: yes, that would work, but is there a way to do it without creating my own token? aka. is there a way to inject it using originally provided string token 'BASE_URL' (similarly how its working in constructors)?
main.ts is generated by template, so I wonder if i can directly use already provided token/provider somehow...

Comment: @yohny, I edited the answer adding an alternative option and a small explanation.